# boost error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

The following code print process current work path. Use boost 1.52, works in visual studio 2010.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "boost/algorithm/string.hpp"
#include "boost/filesystem/path.hpp"
#include "boost/filesystem/operations.hpp"
#include "boost/format.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
        std::string p = boost::filesystem::initial_path<boost::filesystem::path>().string();
        std::cout << p;
        return 0;
}
```

but on linux, when compile it failed, give error message:

```
g++ -g -I/root/boost_1_52_0 -c main.cpp -o main.o
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
main.cpp:9: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
main.cpp:9: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I searched post with same error in stackoverflow, but not got idea how to fix it. Any help is appreciate.

g++ version:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --disable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
```

------------------- Problem Fixed ------------------------

I fix the problem. The reason is that, I changed the boost header file directory name and forget change the include path in makefile at same time.

Later, I enconter the error:

```
boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()
```

It is caused by I copy compiled boost library from other place, for some rease it not compitable with my linux. I recompiled the boost, finnaly all works.

Thanks doctorlove, Igor R, levengli and cv_and_he's help!

Comment: Consider adding the C++ language tag to this so more people read it

Comment: It [appears](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/deprecated.html) as though this function was deprecated. Do you have the same boost version on Windows and Linux?

Comment: boost version is same 1.52

Comment: You are probably not using 1.52 on windows. As you can see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/filesystem/v2/operations.hpp) and [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp), the v2 version of initial_path has a template argument and the v3 one does not. (Boost 1.49.0 was the last version that supplied v2).